# About the convexity of the composition of two convex functions

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

I am starting to learn about convex sets/functions and understand what they are geometrically, but have stumbled upon this:

[image]

How exactly does one show this? It kind of seems like a "duh" statement abstractly but I'm interested in seeing if someone could explain this more concretely

Comment: i would compute the second derivative with respect to $x$

Comment: The statement in the title is wrong, take [$f(x) = \exp(-x)$ as a counterexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXz4f.png).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clearing that up! (should have been more careful with my wording)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner We don't know whether $f,g$ are differentiable or not.

Answer (score 2):

All that we need is the definition of [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition).
Let $x,y$ be in an interval $I$ where $f$ is convex and let $t\in [0,1]$. Then,
$$f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y).$$ 
Moreover, since $g$ is increasing (first inequality) and  convex (second inequality), we get
$$g(f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq g(tf(x)+(1-t)f(y))\leq tg(f(x))+(1-t)g(f(y))$$
which means that $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is convex in $I$.

P.S. Note that the composition of two convex functions is not always convex! Take for example $g(x)=1/x$ and $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ in $(0,+\infty)$. They are both convex, but $g(f(x))=\sqrt{x}$ is not convex.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: In regards to your PS note, is that because in order for the composition of two convex functions to be convex, one of them must be convex AND strictly increasing?

Comment: Yes, the implication holds for $g(f(x))$ if $g$ is also increasing.